# How to make Apache obey to default ACL on Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, apache-http-server, acl

I have set default ACL to allow me doing anything on newly written files. But Apache seems to ignore that, and I don't have access to newly created files. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are meaning the permissions that are controlled by chmod/grp/own, then try using sudo with su ang sg to become that user

> sudo -s
>
> [Password]
>
> sg apache
>
> su apache

Once you have done that, try to use cat to read those files, if that works you are done!

to fix this scenario

> chgrp apache -R `<FOLDER>`
>
> chmod g+rX -R `<FOLDER>`

Otherwise, if you are talking about the extfs acls, which can be seen by files having a + in their ls record

> [mock@vbox ~/footest]$ ls -all
>
> -rw-rwxr--**+** 1 hauna hauna 0 Jul 29 15:14 fileacl
>
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 hauna hauna 0 Jul 29 15:13 filenoacl

this one can be dealt with like the following

> setfacl -m g:apache:rx `<FOLDER>`

If you are taliking about selinux, you will need to change the default context of location where the files are created, this MUST be done as root!

> semanage fcontext -a  -t httpd_sys_content_t '/srv/httproot(/.*)'

that will affect future files, to affect the current ones, use this

> restorecon -R /srv/httproot

I Hope that clears it up,

I would apreciate a post of the error log for apache, and an ls -all of the directory in question, as well as any audit logs (in /var/log/audit/audit.log) that appear about the same time and were denied

Comment: I'm talking about Apache restricting me file access, not vice versa.

Comment: Ah, So, you need a <location FOLDER> block in then apache configs?

so are you getting a 503 error? or do I not have a clear understanding of the problem?

...Seems these boxes do not do newlines...

Comment: No. Apache creates files as Apache, with 700 chmod, so I can't access them. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving the other answer as it is valid for another question!

First you need to change the umask that Apache is running under

> sudo echo "umask 117" > /etc/sysconfig/httpd

this will cause the files that apache creates to be chmod'd 660  (noexec is a good idea)

and then add yourself to the apache group

> sudo usermod -aG apache MYSELF

Comment: You could also modify the code that creates the files to chmod them itself (as apache owns the files, it can chmod them) See PHP's chmod($filename,$mode) function